# Is there a way in R to merge data dataframes that have repeated keys?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two data frames together in R. One is a list of unique places and their accompanying attributes that all have a unique identifier for those places (Dataframe 1). The other is a list of species that come from a smaller subset of those places (dataframe 2). In DF2, there's lots of species that come from the same place (50 species from ~100 places). I'm trying to merge DF1 and DF2 so that each species has the appropriate location information assigned to it.

The columns in DF1 are a mix of Factors (1st col) and numbers

DF1

```
NHDPlusID      StreamLeve   StreamOrde  StreamCalc  
60003700019787  5             1          1  
60003700019816  5             2          2  
60003700019822  5             1          1  
60003700019844  4             1          1  
60003700019882  5             1          1
```

DF2 is also a mix of Factors, numbers, and characters

DF2

```
NHDPlusID      Spec.
60003700019787  A
60003700019816  B
60003700019882  A
60003700019822  C
60003700019787  C
60003700019844  B
60003700019882  A
60003700019822  B
60003700019787  C
```

Desired Outcome

```
NHDPlusID      Spec. StreamLeve StreamOrde StreamCalc
60003700019787  A    5          1          1
60003700019816  B    5          2          2    
60003700019882  A    5          1          1
60003700019822  C    5          1          1    
60003700019787  C    5          1          1
60003700019844  B    4          1          1
60003700019882  A    5          1          1
60003700019822  B    5          1          1
60003700019787  C    5          1          1
```

My initial code was to use

```
DF3<-dplyr::left_join(DF2,DF1, by="NHDPlusID")
```

But using this, everything from DF2 shows up and the columns from DF1 attached to the new DF3 dataframe, but all the values in the attached columns turn to NA.

```
NHDPlusID      Spec. StreamLeve StreamOrde StreamCalc
60003700019787  A    NA          NA          NA
60003700019816  B    NA          NA          NA
60003700019882  A    NA          NA          NA
60003700019822  C    NA          NA          NA
60003700019787  C    NA          NA          NA
60003700019844  B    NA          NA          NA
60003700019882  A    NA          NA          NA
60003700019822  B    NA          NA          NA
60003700019787  C    NA          NA          NA
```

Comment: What have you tried? Joining or merging two or more  tables is an everyday standard problem in data analysis. Please check some good resources for a long term understanding and benefit. A simple left, Right, inner join could help you - many times!

Comment: I've tried both iterations of the join function (left, right). The two DFs combine, but the information in the second dataframe (I've tried putting each one in the x and y position) becomes NAs.

Comment: I followed the data as you posted here and a simple left_join + reorder of columns gives same output as yours. Yes you need to save it in DF2 if you don't want a new DF3. what you mean by `(I've tried putting each one in the x and y position)`

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: My data is sets are very large, but i've edited my initial question to provide some additional information

Answer (score 3):

Your data:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Site = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  Feature1 = c("XX", "XY", "ZZ"),
                  Feature2 = c("YY", "YX", "WW"))

DF2 <- data.frame(Individual = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                  Site = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C"))
```

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

df_desired <- left_join(DF2, DF1, by = "Site")
```

Output:

```
  Individual Site Feature1 Feature2
1          1    A       XX       YY
2          2    B       XY       YX
3          3    A       XX       YY
4          4    C       ZZ       WW
5          5    C       ZZ       WW
6          6    B       XY       YX
7          7    A       XX       YY
8          8    B       XY       YX
9          9    C       ZZ       WW
```

### Answer to edited question

When using your edited dataframes:

`DF1`:

```
    NHDPlusID StreamLeve StreamOrde StreamCalc
1 6.00037e+13          5          1          1
2 6.00037e+13          5          2          2
3 6.00037e+13          5          1          1
4 6.00037e+13          4          1          1
5 6.00037e+13          5          1          1
```

`DF2`:

```
    NHDPlusID Spec.
1 6.00037e+13     A
2 6.00037e+13     B
3 6.00037e+13     A
4 6.00037e+13     C
5 6.00037e+13     C
6 6.00037e+13     B
7 6.00037e+13     A
8 6.00037e+13     B
9 6.00037e+13     C
```

And running the following code will produce your desired dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
  
df_desired <- left_join(DF2, DF1, by = "NHDPlusID")
df_desired
```

Output:

```
    NHDPlusID Spec. StreamLeve StreamOrde StreamCalc
1 6.00037e+13     A          5          1          1
2 6.00037e+13     B          5          2          2
3 6.00037e+13     A          5          1          1
4 6.00037e+13     C          5          1          1
5 6.00037e+13     C          5          1          1
6 6.00037e+13     B          4          1          1
7 6.00037e+13     A          5          1          1
8 6.00037e+13     B          5          1          1
9 6.00037e+13     C          5          1          1
```

Which as you can see, is your desired dataframe.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, and while yes the dataframes do merge together, the values in the columns of the second DF all become NAs and none of the information transfers over. The information from the first DF is there though.

Comment: @John, I added code after you edited your question.

Answer (score 2):

Using base R:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  Site = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Feature1 = c("XX", "XY", "ZZ"),
  Feature2 = c("YY", "YX", "WW")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  Individual = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L),
  Site = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C")
)
merge(df2, df1, by = "Site")[c(2,1,3:4)]

#>   Individual Site Feature1 Feature2
#> 1          1    A       XX       YY
#> 2          3    A       XX       YY
#> 3          7    A       XX       YY
#> 4          2    B       XY       YX
#> 5          8    B       XY       YX
#> 6          6    B       XY       YX
#> 7          5    C       ZZ       WW
#> 8          4    C       ZZ       WW
#> 9          9    C       ZZ       WW
```

Comment: I have tried this and the new dataframe just becomes an empty one with all of the column headers of the two starting DFs.

Comment: Please, try with the dataframes I have just added to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

using your data for df1 and df2 copy paste :

```
df1 <- read_table('Site Feature1 Feature2
A     XX      YY
B     XY      YX
C     ZZ      WW ')

df2 <- read_table('Individual Site
1          A
2          B
3          A
4          C
5          C
6          B
7          A
8          B
9          C')
```

Now to get same output as yours: simply left join- df2 with df1 and not other way- by "site" and reorder the columns. Now if you assign the output to DF2 it will be saved!

```
df2 <- dplyr::left_join(x=df2,y=df1,by=c('Site'))%>%select(Individual,everything())
```

now following the steps; df2 has become :

```
df2
> df2
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Individual Site  Feature1 Feature2
       <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <chr>   
1          1 A     XX       YY      
2          3 A     XX       YY      
3          7 A     XX       YY      
4          2 B     XY       YX      
5          6 B     XY       YX      
6          8 B     XY       YX      
7          4 C     ZZ       WW      
8          5 C     ZZ       WW      
9          9 C     ZZ       WW
```

What is the error you are getting? Please ensure to use `<-`